# Calling Rails workers from gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm building a gem for my rails app, and I want to call some of my rails workers from the gem. As far as I know, we can call any of the gem's methods from our rails app once the gem is included in our app, but we can't call rails methods from that gem. Is there any method to do that, or can I write workers in my gem?

I'm using resque for my workers and there is a limitation that I can't use other gems like delayed_job.

Comment: Please clarify your question, and paste your Gemfile

Comment: he is saying that he is building a gem only for his app so i don't think you need to see his Gemfile, and he want to call workers written in his app from that gem , possible ??